# How to put 10+ variables in one ( PHP )

Tags: php, html

trying to put

`$var1 - $var2 - $var3 - etc` in one `$collection = $var1.$var2.$var3` to use `$collection` in echo.

As an example, `$var1` is the opening html for a html table `$var1 = '<tr><td>';` and `$var2` is an actual `variable`.

So far : `$collection = $var1.$var2.$var3`has not worked out. The table prints empty.

Is there anything I'm missing?

EDIT: Found the issue. The first solution worked out, however I had to include my config file before it. Being dumb, I forgot to do it.

Comment: please paste your full code

Comment: do you want to append those vars or you want to create  an array from them ?

Comment: What is $collection. Please paste your code.

Comment: Your being too simplistic. If you are trying to construct a page template then do some reading on that topic. Its not easy you would be better off looking into an existing library

Comment: If you're numbering variables like this, then you have a prime facie case for using an array instead

Answer (score 0):

Your coode should look like this

```
<?php

$var1='<tr><td>';
$var2='Hello';
$var3='</td></tr>';

$collection=$var1.$var2.$var3;

echo $collection;
```

Is the what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your vars are filled with contents.
2. Then you can do.

`$collection = $var1.$var2.$var3;`

`echo $collection;`

When you still recieve empty activate your error reporting for showing eventual other errors.